# MultiJson::LoadError: 795: unexpected token when trying to parse incoming body request

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

I'm losing my sanity trying to parse an incoming request on a Sinatra app.

This is my spec

```
 payload = File.read("./spec/support/fixtures/payload.json")
 post "/api/v1/verify_payload", { :payload => payload }
 last_response.body.must_equal payload
```

where is simply spec/support/fixtures/payload.json

```
{"ref":"refs/heads/master"}
```

My route looks like

```
post '/verify_payload' do
  params =  MultiJson.load(request.body.read, symbolize_keys: true)
  params[:payload]
end
```

And running the spec I get the following error:

```
MultiJson::LoadError: 795: unexpected token at 'payload=%7B%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%7D'
```

I have tried to parse the body request in different ways without luck.

How can I make the request valid JSON?

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a JSON-encoded POST body, you have to set the Content-Type header to application/json. With Rack::Test, you should be able to do this:

```
post "/api/v1/verify_payload", payload, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
```

Alternatively:

```
header 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
post '/api/v1/verify_payload'
```

More info here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/testing.html

Comment: ```post "/api/v1/verify_payload", payload, 'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'``` produces the exact same error.

Comment: Yes, the payload is still seen as ```%7B%22ref%22%3A%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%7D``` instead to be properly formatted.

Comment: If the request.body does still include `payload=`, that doesn't really make any sense to me, since you're not sending a payload key with the new post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it is that you are passing a ruby hash, that is not well formated, you should pass a json object.

Something like this, should work:

post "/api/v1/verify_payload", { :payload => payload.to_json }